# Query 2 COUNTS with a GROUP BY statement trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query a count from registered users and enrolled users for each group in the table.

However, I keep getting duplicates of the Group names, registered, and enrolled. I need it to be just the unique group name with the count in its respective column. I am a novice, and I've been wrapping my head around this for 3 days. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. below is what I am closest with, but still getting duplicate group names.

```
WITH CTE_GROUP as (
    SELECT DISTINCT [GROUP] AS GROUPS
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE AUTH_PAGE = 'X' AND CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) >= '2022-04-01' AND CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) < '2022-05-01' AND EMAIL IS NOT NULL AND EMAIL <> '' AND EMAIL NOT LIKE '%@company.com' OR CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) >= '2022-04-01' AND CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) < '2022-05-01' AND EMAIL IS NOT NULL AND EMAIL <> '' AND EMAIL NOT LIKE '%@company.com'
    GROUP BY [GROUP]
),
CTE_REGISTERED as (
    SELECT [GROUP], COUNT (*) AS REGISTERED
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) >= '2022-04-01' AND CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) < '2022-05-01' AND EMAIL IS NOT NULL AND EMAIL <> '' AND EMAIL NOT LIKE '%@company.com'
    GROUP BY [GROUP]
),
CTE_ENROLLED as (
    SELECT [GROUP], COUNT (*) AS ENROLLED
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE AUTH_PAGE = 'X' AND CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) >= '2022-04-01' AND CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) < '2022-05-01' AND EMAIL IS NOT NULL AND EMAIL <> '' AND EMAIL NOT LIKE '%@company.com'
    GROUP BY [GROUP]
)
SELECT DISTINCT GROUPS, REGISTERED, ENROLLED
FROM CTE_GROUP, CTE_REGISTERED, CTE_ENROLLED
```

My results come out to this.

```
GROUPS               REGISTERED       ENROLLED
CompanyA              3                 2
CompanyB              3                 3
CompanyA              3                 2
CompanyB              3                 3
```

The result I am looking for should be

```
GROUPS               REGISTERED       ENROLLED
CompanyA              3                 2
CompanyB              3                 3
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a quick glance.  Your final query should be using joins on "group".  Otherwise, you are getting all possible combinations of the records in the 3 tables.  I would start with a left join.  Also, use aliases for the tables to so that columns can be explicitly identified as to which table they are from.

Comment: @SchmitzIT please read [Should I explain my downvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not) (and no, it wasn't me).

Comment: Add to that and OP hasn't even read the new user guidance to the site... which is recommended as part of the join process. And reading that explains how the site works to they are aware its a bit different to other similar sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need a "**conditional aggregate**" in a single query:

```
SELECT
      [group]
    , count(*) AS registered
    , count(CASE WHEN AUTH_PAGE = 'X' THEN 1 END) AS enrolled
FROM table1
WHERE CreationDate >= '20220401'
    AND CreationDate < '20220501'
    AND EMAIL NOT LIKE '%@company.com'
GROUP BY
     [group]
;
```

In essence you use a `case expression` inside an aggregation function, such as `count()` and this way your count inherits the "condition(s)" defined through that `case expression`.

Also note you do NOT need to cast those [CreationDate] to "date" for the where clause predicates to work. All date/time related data types can be compared to date literals. Furthermore, in SQL Server, the "safest" date literal is just in YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: I tried doing case statements before that were similar to this, but I kept getting errors for lack of knowledge on proper syntax. This worked perfectly though. Basically you nested your case statement in the count, correct? Greatly appreciate pointing me in the right direction and assistance.

Comment: Yes, **"nesting the case EXPRESSION"** into the count: nb `case` is NOT as "statement" - all that a case expression does is evaluate to a single value, and something that evaluates to a single value is an "expression".  (but: I know there is confusion out there on this sematic point)

Answer (score 0):

Your resultset is basically a `CROSS JOIN`, because you do not have `JOIN` conditions between the three CTEs.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    CTE_GROUP AS [Groups] 
    INNER JOIN CTE_Registered AS [Registered] ON [Groups].[GROUPS] = [Registered].[GROUP]
    INNER JOIN CTE_ENROLLED AS [Enrolled] ON [Groups].[GROUPS] = [Enrolled].[GROUP]
```

In general, when you are dealing with data from multiple tables (whether they are actual physical tables, views, or in-memory tables), you will need to let the database engine know how this data is related. You do so by creating relationships (using primary and foreign keys), and by instructing the engine in the query using the `JOIN` conditions. Tables can be related through more than one field, in which case you can string them together in the `JOIN` condition just like a `WHERE` clause.

Be aware that there are multiple ways to perform a `JOIN`, and the outcome will depend on whether or not you use the correct type. In the example query I provided, I'm using an `INNER JOIN`, which ensures you only get results returned that exist in both tables from included in the `JOIN`.

Comment: Since I was pulling from only 1 table, I had tried an inner join though not through my CTE's. I had only gone to CTE's because I couldnt get my sub queries to work. I kept getting errors because I couldnt figure out the correct syntax.  This does work somewhat with my CTE's though it creates three extra columns with the group name. The conditional aggregate gave me exactly what was required, but this definitely gave me some ideas on other reports I am working on. Greatly appreciate the feedback. Thanks

Comment: @nthingwerks Oh, if you only want 1 group name, you can replace the `SELECT *` with `SELECT Group.GROUPS, [Registered].REGISTERED, [Enrolled].ENROLLED` instead. So you explicitly only select the column from the groups CTE. I didn't look at the actual individual queries you use to construct the CTEs, so I didn't catch it's all coming out of the same table. I agree that the conditional aggregate is a much cleaner solution, but hope the input on how to use `JOIN` conditions will help you going forward :)